# Since Int32 is a value type why does it inherit .ToString()?

Tags: c#, .net, tostring, value-type, reference-type

[These are the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspx) about `.ToString()` that has prompted this question.  They state:

> Because Object is the base class of all reference types in the .NET
>   Framework, this behavior [.ToString()] is inherited by reference types that do not
>   override the ToString method.

Yet further on it goes to state:

> For example, the base types such as Char, Int32, and String provide ToString implementations

However Int32 is a **struct** and hence must be a *value type*.

So what's going on here?  Does Int32 implement it's very own .ToString() which has nothing to do with Object?

Comment: I am pretty sure it has to do with boxing.

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1694055.aspx/1?Reference+types+and+Value+types+Inheritance+from+Object+class

Comment: @MBen I am pretty sure the question and answer have nothing to do with boxing.

Comment: It sounds like maybe you are confused about how it is that a value type can inherit from a reference type, which is a bit like being confused about how you can put a red box inside a blue box -- surely you can only put blue boxes inside other blue boxes, right? No, you can put a red box in a blue box, and you can derive a value type from a reference type too.  This might help: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/09/19/inheritance-and-representation.aspx

Comment: Note that the documentation that you quote says that "`Object` is the base class of all reference types in the .NET Framework." However, this does NOT imply that everything that has `Object` in its inheritance hierarchy is a reference type. (All cats are in the class *Mammalia* but not all species in the class *Mammalia* are cats.) It is perfectly legal for a value type to inherit from a reference type, and in fact, all `struct` derive from `ValueType` (itself a reference type)` and `ValueType` derives from `Object`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Int32 is a struct and therefore a value type.
But:

```
System.Object
   System.ValueType
      System.Int32
```

Int32 derives from System.ValueType and this itself derives from System.Object. Et voilà...

Comment: have you ever seen a struct-declaration like `public struct Foo : System.Object`...? i am wondering how they get this to compile :) if you ever decompile `System.Int32` you'll get `public struct Int32 : IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible, IComparable<int>, IEquatable<int>` ... but still having a baseType `System.ValueType`... strange, isn't it?

Comment: Excellent this helped me to understand - so is there something special about `System.ValueType` that makes the runtime handle it differently?

Comment: @m.edmondson that is the part i've never understood neither ... i *guess* it is special by the clr ... i think the .net-clr-specification book from microsoft (sth like this: http://www.amazon.de/Programming-Language-Covering-Microsoft-Development/dp/0321741765/ref=sr_1_22?ie=UTF8&qid=1321453023&sr=8-22) will cover that magic :)

Comment: I think it would be handy is @Jon could elaborate on that!

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair: What is it specifically that you are wondering about? I assure you that there's nothing magical about it; it's a straightfoward compiler.

Comment: @Andreas Niedermair: That's not legal per the specification. The specification spells out exactly that you can't explicitly derive from `System.ValueType` and that there's a special reserved word `struct` that accomplishes this, and that when you use it to mark a type definition, you can only list interfaces that the type implements but not a base class (again, it implicitly derives from `System.ValueType`).

Comment: @EricLippert @Jason got it straight! ... the `struct` keyword implies `System.ValueType` ... thanks @Jason!

Answer (score 11):

Yes, `Int32` overrides `ToString`... although that's somewhat irrelevant here. *All* types inherit the members of `object` - you can *always* call `ToString()`, you can *always* call `Equals` etc. (`ValueType` overrides `Equals` and `GetHashCode` for you, although you should almost always override them further in structs to provide a more efficient implementation.)

Note that you can override the methods yourself very easily:

```
public struct Foo
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "some dummy text";
    }
}
```

It's not clear which aspect is confusing you (there are quite a few different areas involved here). If you could clarify, we could address the specific issue.

Comment: i guess he's confused with the fact, that value types behave like value types but inherit from object, which is a class and hence a reference type ..

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair: More than that, they inherit from `ValueType` which is itself a class :)

Comment: jup, know that, just wanted to get this very straight :)

Comment: Thanks Jon - it was _your_ article about value + reference types which made me start thinking about this.  The confusion lies in the statement `Object is the base class of all reference types` and hence inherits `.ToString` so why does Int32 also inherit this?

Comment: Being the base class for all reference types doesn't mean it cannot be in the inheritance hierarchy for all value types as well.

Comment: see my comment @http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152761/since-int32-is-a-value-type-why-does-it-inherit-tostring/8152830#8152830

Comment: @m.edmondson, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.valuetype.aspx) for the value type object hierarchy.

Comment: @JonSkeet -  So is there something special about `System.ValueType` that means the CLR treats it differently?

Comment: @m.edmondson: Yes - the CLR knows about `System.ValueType` and `System.Enum`. They're very special types.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps you confusion arises from not realizing that value types inherit from `Object`? Here is the inheritance graph of `System.Object`, `System.ValueType`, `System.Int32` and `MyNamespace.Customer` which is supposed to be a class of you own making. I was lazy and didn't write all the public methods and interfaces of `Int32`.

[image: UML]

`ToString` is declared in `Object` but is overriden both in `ValueType` and in `Int32`.

Answer (score 0):

The docs are wrong. Both reference and value types inherit that behavior from object (but do remember that [not everything in .NET is a class that derives from object](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/08/06/not-everything-derives-from-object.aspx)).

All (most?) core value types override ToString() to return something more sensible than the class name.

Comment: The documentation quoted above is correct. Why do you believe it is incorrect?

Comment: @ERic Lippert:  If value types inherit from ValueType, that would suggest one can use value types anyplace one may use ValueType.  That doesn't work, though: ValueType satisfies a class constraint but not a struct constraint, whereas value types satisfy a struct constraint but not a class constraint.  If one assigns a struct with a mutating interface (e.g. the `List` enumerator) to a variable of type `ValueType`, the resulting variable will behave as a mutable class type, rather than a mutable value type.

Comment: @supercat: There's a bit of a logical fallacy in your argument. If a struct S inherits from ValueType then one expects that (1) all members of ValueType are also members of S; that's the definition of "inheritance". And (2) that a value of type S may be assigned to a variable of type ValueType (in this case, via a boxing conversion). But those are both facts about *instances* of S. There is no requirement that *the type* S be usable everywhere that *the type* ValueType may legally be used.

Comment: @supercat: think about it this way: an apple is a kind of fruit. If you have a bowl that can contain fruit, then that bowl can contain an apple; apples are assignment-compatible with fruit. All fruit have a property "taste"; apples have that property because they are fruit. Apples inherit properties from fruit. But that does not mean that you can substitute *the word* "apple" everywhere that *the word* fruit appears and preserve the truth of a sentence! "The word 'fruit' begins with the letter 'f'" cannot be substituted with "apple" and preserve its truth.

Comment: @EricLippert: Conversion from an unboxed value type to ValueType is a representation-changing conversion.  Conversion of a boxed value type to ValueType is representation-preserving.  To my mind, that would suggest that "boxed value types" are effectively class-type objects that inherit from ValueType, but unboxed ones are not.  Instead, they are implicitly convertible to boxed value types, which do inherit from ValueType.  The wrinkle is that a request to JIT code which would work with a parameter, variable, or field that's derivative of ValueType...

Comment: @EricLippert: ...will produce code which manipulates the entity directly rather than via heap reference.  As I think about it, I'm somewhat impressed with the .net 2.0 people who managed to make generics work as well as they do.  It might be interesting to ponder how things might have worked if there had been a means for heap-reference objects to exhibit value semantics (meaning that a copy could not just be a blit, but would have to recursively copy any nested heap-references that were supposed to have value semantics), but that would have complicated things further.

Comment: @EricLippert: I guess my biggest confusion is how to describe the type of what's passed in to a parameter, to distinguish boxed value types from real value types.  My inclination would be to regard variables/fields/parameters of value types as being outside the type system.  Consider calling `bool f<T>(T bar) where T:IEnumerator<Integer> {return bar.MoveNext();}` with either a variable of type List.Enumerator<Integer>, or a variable of type IEnumerator<Integer> which holds a List.Enumerator<Integer>.  How would you describe the type of the instance passed in `bar` in each case?

Comment: @supercat: You are confusing *inheritance* with *assignment compatibility*. *Inheritance* is the property *of types* that members of a base type are also members of a derived type; inheritance has nothing to do with how the bits look in memory. An unboxed value type is not assignment-compatible with a variable of type ValueType, but the value type still inherits all the members of its base class.

Comment: @EricLippert: An unboxed value may be assigned to one of ValueType without an explicit typecast (though not vice versa).

Answer (score 0):

I think the short answer to your question is that value types inherit from [System.ValueType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.valuetype.aspx) and that in turn inherits from object.

Answer (score 0):

Every `struct` have inheritance from `System.ValueType` class *(not allowed)* which is done solely by the compiler. All `struct` have methods from `ValueType` base class which is inherited from `Object` class makes us have access to `ToString()` and all others.

Even though `ValueType` is inherited from `Object` class but it has special implementation of the overrides.