# What is the best way to derive a unique dictionary key for an object?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

### PROBLEM

I need a method for generating keys for a dictionary of objects.  However, I have a few requirements that are making this a bit difficult.  Here is the scenario:

1. The Dictionary is a list of reference type objects.
2. The Dictionary is `private`, within a static class.
3. External code needs to obtain a key to specific objects within the dictionary, but MUST NOT have access to the objects within the dictionary, or the dictionary itself.
4. Given a specific object within the dictionary, the key must be consistently re-calculable/derivable.  If properties on the object change, the key MUST NOT CHANGE.
5. Conversely, if a new object is created that can evaluate to being `equal` to another object within the dictionary, the key must be different since they are two, separate objects.
6. This implementation must be thread safe.

### NON-SOLUTIONS

**Solution #1**
All .Net objects contain a method called `.GetHashCode()`, which returns an integer value.  You can use this as a key.

**Problem**
Not possible.  MSDN States:

> Two objects that are equal return hash codes that are equal.

This breaks req #5 and I assume (but not tested) req. #4.  I would love to have an option like this, if it could meet these rules.

**Solution #2**
Convert the pointer to the object to an `int` and use that as a key.

**Problem**
This breaks the essence of req. #3.  Passing pointers, and using them as keys doesn't feel safe.

**Solution #3**
Convert the pointer to the object to an integer *hash the value* and use the hash as a key.

**Problem**
Although this doesn't break any rules, I'd prefer to avoid accessing pointers since this would involve using `unsafe` code.  I'm not opposed to using unsafe code if I have to, but I'd prefer to avoid it if at all possible.

### CONCLUSION

Maybe my requirements are a bit picky.  There has to be some reasonable way of deriving a key from a unique object.  Has anyone ever experienced such a scenario and solved this dilemma?

Comment: Isn't 4 contradicting itself, and number 5?

Comment: How about generating guids for each object when adding them to the dictionary and use that as the key?

Comment: Solution 3 absolutely will not work. The GC is free to move your object at any time and so you both risk ending up with a hash/ object ptr disconnect (probably not too bad) or another object being placed at your pointer location (potential key clash and a hideous "heisenbug" to fix.

Comment: @DavidArno Guid is in direct conflict with requirement 4: "the key most be consistently re-calculable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> 1 The Dictionary is a list of ByRef objects.

Objects are always 'by reference' in .NET. This may be the beginning of the misunderstanding. Reference equality is what you need/want.

> 3 External code needs to obtain a key to specific objects within the dictionary, but MUST NOT have access to the objects within the dictionary, or the dictionary itself.

This is the real problem. Without it, a reference to the object itself would have worked. But the framework still provides all of your functionality, right off-the-shelf:

```
private Dictionary<object, MyClass> _myStore;

// add an item and return a key    
public object Add(MyClass item)
{
    object key = new object();
    _myStore.Add(key, item);
    return key;
}
```

And to satisfy req #4:

```
private Dictionary<object, MyClass> _itemForKey;    // was _myStore
private Dictionary<MyClass, object> _keyForItem;


// add an item and return a key    
public object Add(MyClass item)
{
    object key = new object();
    _itemForKey.Add(key, item);
    _keyForItem.Add(item, key);
    return key;
}

protected object DeriveKeyFromItem(MyClass item)
{
   return _keyForItem[item];
}
```

Note: these samples are not thread-safe (req 6), but that's a standard feature to resolve.

Comment: That's a really neat solution. +1

Comment: Probably considered pedantic but `Objects are always 'by reference' in .NET` is not true since `System.ValueType` is itself is inherited from `System.Object`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152761/since-int32-is-a-value-type-why-does-it-inherit-tostring

Comment: Although to fulfil the 4th requirement you need a second dictionary to may back from values to keys but that should not be difficult to add.

Comment: @m.edmondson  But ValueTypes are not objects.

Comment: @user1937198 - Yes, for the derivable part. But that may be superfluous now. Otherwise you will indeed need a 2nd dictionary.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - Surely it is?  It's a derivation from System.Object and inherits all it's functionality such as `GetType()` and `ToString()`.

Comment: Thank you, Henk.  Simple, and elegant, but as user1937198 pointed out, that breaks rule #4.  Happen to have any thoughts on Tim S. solution?

Comment: @m.edmondson - this depends on very exact use of terminology. Any valuetype instance IS-A System.Object but they're not objects.

Comment: Rule #4 and #6 are easily implemented, it would have been easier to answer if you had provided code for desired use. I'll add an outline.

Comment: I need to execute batches of SQL commands in transactions.  Multiple transactions, for the same db connection, may exist.  I need a way of referencing the SqlTransaction object, from outside of my DB processor class, without passing around the transaction object.  This is a simplistic explanation of the requirement.

Comment: FYI, your solution is looking better.  This may be the answer I need.

Comment: @m.edmondson: Given `int foo=34; object bar=foo;`, variable `foo`, of type `System.Int32`, will hold a collection of bits which is *not* an object, but the assignment to `bar` will create a heap object of type `System.Int32` which does derive from `ValueType` and `Object`, and which holds the same data that `foo` held.  Basically, there's a universe of variable types and a universe of heap object types; each type definition adds a type into both universes.  C# tries to pretend that there's no difference between the types, but the reality is that they are in fact different.

Comment: @m.edmondson: Storage locations of types other than `System.Enum` which inherit from `ValueType` exhibit value semantics, while heap objects of *all* types, including those derived from `ValueType`, exhibit reference semantics.

Comment: You probably want to use a [`ConditionalWeakTable<TKey, TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.conditionalweaktable-2.getvalue?view=netframework-4.8) for `_keyForItem`. That avoids the issue where two distinct objects placed in the dictionary might be equal, creating a collision. Also, it avoids the memory leak if you needed to be able to keep the original key associated with the object even after the value is removed.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your requirement boils down to that you want to compare and hash by reference equality. Using this as the `IEqualityComparer<T>` in your dictionary will do that, using [`RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/11tbk3h9.aspx) and [`object.ReferenceEquals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.referenceequals.aspx).

```
public class ReferenceEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    public bool Equals(T x, T y)
    {
        return object.ReferenceEquals(x, y);
    }
    public int GetHashCode(T obj)
    {
        return System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(obj);
    }
}
```

Note that since pointers and references [aren't the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430112/what-is-the-difference-between-a-c-sharp-reference-and-a-pointer), your reference shouldn't be usable as a pointer, reducing the risk of `unsafe` code using this inappropriately.

Comment: Bingo, I think you have the answer.  Rather simple too.  I'll attempt to implement this and if this works as I hope, you have the answer mark.

Answer (score -1):

How about defining a structure something like:

```
public struct BlindIdentityToken : IEquatable<BlindIdentityToken>
{
    Object o;
    public BlindIdentityToken(Object obj)
    {
        o = obj;
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(o);
    }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null || obj.GetType() != typeof(BlindIdentityToken))
            return false;
        return ((BlindIdentityToken)obj).o == o;
    }
    public bool Equals(BlindIdentityToken other)
    {
        return o == other.o;
    }
}
```

Given a reference to an object, one may construct a `BlindIdentityToken` which will compare equal to any other `BlindIdentityToken` constructed for the same object, but will compare unequal to anything else.  Because it is a structure type and implements `IEquatable<BlindIdentityToken>`, constructing a token and looking it up in a dictionary will not require a heap allocation.  Because it uses `RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode()` it should ignore any override of `GetHashCode` by the object whose reference is encapsulated, and because `o` is a private field, it is somewhat protected from outside code sneaking a reference to it.